# PostgreSQL, drop tables with query

Tags: postgresql

I have such query to list tables in current database:

```
SELECT c.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c 
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
WHERE c.relkind 
IN ('r','') AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') AND
pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
```

I am trying to drop all those tables using upper SELECT like subquery:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS (SELECT c.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c 
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
WHERE c.relkind 
IN ('r','') AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') AND
pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)) as tname
```

But that don't work.
How to propery write  a query which will drop all tables listed by showed SELECT query?
For now I use DataReader for loop through query result and drop tables by one.
But I think that may go 'at once'.

Comment: If your intention is to drop all objects of the user, this can be done much easier using `drop owned by your_pg_username`

Comment: Hm, for those tables owner is 'postgres'. Can that finish good? I would also like to delete my user functions so getting it with subquery will be more useful to my purposes.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to use the superuser (postgres) to create your own stuff - and this is one of the reasons why. Another (more important) reason is, that it means that your application connects to the database with superuser privileges which is a security hole wide open.

Comment: Yes, I have to change that and I will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL for this, which in turn can only be used in a procedural language like PL/pgSQL, something like this:

```
do
$$
declare
   stmt text;
   table_rec record;
begin
   for table_rec in (SELECT c.relname as tname
                     FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c 
                       LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace 
                     WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','') 
                       AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') 
                       AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid))
   loop
     execute 'drop table '||table_rec.tname||' cascade';
   end loop;
end;
$$
```

Comment: Never before see that so I have to try if it work from .NET and it works. That deletes all wanted tables. So, same way I try to delete my user functions " execute 'drop function '||func_rec.fname||' cascade';" but get error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cascade"
LINE 1: drop function first_agg cascade
                                ^
QUERY:  drop function first_agg cascade
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 14 at EXECUTE statement. Can be visible from here why that happens?

Comment: @user973238: `drop function` doesn't have a `cascade` option. But `drop owned ` will take care of all that for you.

Comment: That can lead to same problem since all function are owned from 'postgres' again. I can successfully drop function with 'cascade' from pgAdmin, otherwise can't. Anyway, for deleting user functions I created a new question. Feel free to join :) and thank you for helping.

Comment: Again: why do you create your own functions as the superuser? You should create a regular user that owns all of that.

Comment: I want to drop triggers fetching from this query * select event_object_schema as table_schema,event_object_table as table_name,trigger_schema,trigger_name,string_agg(event_manipulation, ',') as event,action_timing as activation,
action_condition as condition,action_statement as definition from information_schema.triggers where event_object_table like 'his_%' and trigger_name ='set_timestamp' group by 1,2,3,4,6,7,8
order by table_schema,table_name

Answer (score 2):

You can "generate" your DROP statement using a SELECT statement.  For example:

```
SELECT 'DROP TABLE "' + table_name + '"' 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE '[your_prefix_here]%'
```

(Replace '[your_prefix_here]%' with your conditions and wild cards)

Comment: This does not work for me. I get an error saying '+' operator doesn't belong there.

Comment: @user2233706 You can use || instead of +